# C++ how to deal with error appeared deep in objects composition?

Tags: c++, exception

Here each new method call must be checked against error and this really ... slow at least.
I am thinking about exceptions, but i read they are not good for handling errors.
For instance if i will throw exception, i must handle it probably with the previous method on stack, because otherwise there can be local variable pointing to allocated space in that method, so i can't skip it.
So is there any good approach?

```
class A {
  int method() {
     ...; 
     return 1;
  }
};

class B {
  A a;
  int method() {
    int err = a.method();
     if (err == 1) {
       ...;
       return ret;
     }
  }
};

class C {
  B b;
  int method() {
     int err = b.method();
     if (err == 1) {
       ...;
       return ret;
     }
   }
};

int main() {
  C c;
  int err = c.method();
  if (err == 1) {}
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Exceptions are the generalized approach in C++ to handling _exceptional_ situations.  Handling errors is something they are designed for.  I'm not really sure what your asking in terms of their downsides (they _do_ have downsides, though).

Comment: @Krab: semi_initialised, semi_terminated -- my code looked similar some 20 years ago before I knew about C++ Exception Handling.

Comment: When using exceptions you can easily leak because of the "raw" resource management C++ allows to its users. By storing objects on your stack by value (by employing RAII http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) you can make exception usage safer. Despite this there are several C++ projects where error handling is not exception-driven, the low-level nature of C++ (and sometimes mixed-in C code) is often not a good combination with exceptions because exceptions can increase the vulnerability to resource leaks in case of programming mistakes.

Comment: I think the code you suggested is a bit too abstract. You should at least mention, what the objects should represent and what the methods should do. Other than that, C++ Exceptions are clearly superior to return codes, especially if a method deep in the stack can cause the entire hierarchy to fail.

Comment: @krab While I don't disagree with all the points raised there, not using exceptions and relying on error codes just make the complication of proper error handling "someone else's oroblem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of the following methods to deal with errors deep in functions -- whether they arise out of object composition or layers of functions is not relevant.

**Method 1: Throw exceptions deep in a low level functions.**

```
struct my_error_A {};

class A {
  void method() {
      if ( ... )
      {
         throw my_error_A();
      }
     ...; 
  }
};

struct my_error_B {};

class B {
  A a;
  void method() {
    a.method();
       ...;
      if ( ... )
      {
         throw my_error_B();
      }
  }
};

struct my_error_C {};

class C {
  B b;
  void method() {
     b.method();
       ...;
      if ( ... )
      {
         throw my_error_C();
      }
   }
};

int main() {
  C c;
  try
  {
     c.method();
  }
  catch (my_error_A err)
  {
     // Deal with errors from A.
  }

  catch (my_error_B err)
  {
     // Deal with errors from B.
  }

  catch (my_error_C err)
  {
     // Deal with errors from C.
  }

  catch (...)
  {
     // Deal with all othe exceptions.
  }

  return 0;  
}
```

**Method 2: Use a global error code holder to keep track of errors.**

```
int globalErrorCode = 0;

class A {
    void method() {
        a.method();
        ...;
        if ( ... )
        {
           globalErrorCode = A::errorCode;
        }
    }
  static int errorCode;
};

class B {
  A a;
  void method() {
      a.method();
      if ( globalErrorCode != 0 )
      {
         return;
      }
      ...;
      if ( ... )
      {
         globalErrorCode = B::error_code;
         return;
      }
      ...;
  }
  static int errorCode;
};

class C {
  B b;
  void method() {
      b.method();
      if ( globalErrorCode != 0 )
      {
         return;
      }
      ...;
      if ( ... )
      {
         globalErrorCode = C::error_code;
         return;
      }
      ...;
  }
  static int errorCode;
};

int main() {
  C c;
  c.method();
  if ( globalErrorCode != 0 )
  {
     // Deal with error code.
  }
  return 0;  
}
```

**Method 3: Return error codes at every level and deal with them at every level.**

```
class A {
  int method() {
      if ( ... )
      {
         return A::errorCode;
      }
     ...; 
  }
  static int errorCode;
};

class B {
  A a;
  int method() {
      int err = a.method();
      if ( err != 0 )
      {
         return err;
      }
      ...;
      if ( ... )
      {
         return B::errorCode;
      }
  }

  static int errorCode;
};

class C {
    B b;
    int method() {
        int err = b.method();
        if ( err != 0 )
        {
           return err;
        }
        ...;
        if ( ... )
        {
           return C::errorCode;
        }
    }
    static int errorCode;
};

int main() {
  C c;
  int err = c.method();
  if ( err != 0 )
  {
     // Deal with errors
  }

  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: yes -- making error variables static or global is certainly helpful to advertise the design as being from a beginner.

Comment: @GrapschKnutsch, I love to hear your designs to deal with the OP's problem.

Comment: @Sahu: I'm sorry -- but to avoid using global or static variables is one of my favored guidelines since nearly 30 years of software design.

Comment: @GrapschKnutsch, I understand your concern. There are times and places where your concern is valid -- anything a little more complex than a homework or class project. However, for small projects, using a global or static variable is not going to hurt. For what it's worth, I have been designing software for over 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{   void method()
    {
    }
};

class B
{   A a;
    void method()
    {   a.method();
    }
};

class C
{   B b;
    void method()
    {   b.method();
    }
};

int main()
{   try
    {   C c;
        c.method();
        return 0;
    } catch (const std::exception &e)
    {   std::cerr << "Failure: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If you have pointers to local objects and the pointers might live longer than the objects pointed to, you're doing something very simply WRONG. Such a design is a recipe for a crash.